# Prove that if $f$ is an holomorphic function with certain conditions then $f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

Prove that if $f$ is an holomorphic function on $H=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : \, Im(z)>0\}$ such that $ \exists a,b\in \mathbb{R} $ with $a<b$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{z \to x}f(z)=0\quad \forall x\in (a,b)$ then $f(z)=0$, $z \in H$.

Any idea about how to start?

Comment: Have you already heard about the reflection principle?

Comment: But only for harmonic functions

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic. (Thus a holomorphic function is harmonic too, but let's focus on real-valued functions for the moment.) Try to use the reflection of harmonic functions to obtain a reflection for holomorphic functions. Then the extended (by reflection) holomorphic function will vanish identically on the segment $(a,b)$. The identity theorem does the rest.